# Django for loop data not displaying in template

Tags: python, json, django, list, django-views

I am not saving data in my data base. I am using an api service and I don't want to to save those api data in my data base. I just want to display those data in my html template. The problem only first data of for loop showing in template where I can see all for loop data from my terminal. I want to display my all for loop data in my html template. here is my code:

**views.py:**

```
for i in  results[search_type]:
     if search_type == "organic_results":
     title = i["title"]
     print(title) 

context = {"title":title}
```

I know I can use append method but it's showing all data together in my template as list. I want to so theme in my template using for loop like this:

**html**

```
{%for i in title %}{{i}}{%endfor%}
```

my terminal result:

```
Facebook - Log In or Sign Up
https://www.facebook.com/
Newsroom | Meta - Facebook
https://about.fb.com/news/
Facebook - Apps on Google Play
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana&hl=en_US&gl=US
Facebook - Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook
Facebook Careers | Do the Most Meaningful Work of Your ...
https://www.facebookcareers.com/
Facebook - Twitter
https://twitter.com/facebook
```

why only first data of for loop showing in my template?

Comment: When you are looping, you are able to see all the data in your terminal because you are using a print statement in your for loop, but at the last loop cycle `title = i['title']` is storing the last value in `title` variable, it's not saving all of them, that's why you are seeing only one title in your template but all of them in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

You are showing only one title on template because you are passing only one title to the context.

You could use something like this on your view:

```
titles = []
for i in  results[search_type]:
    if search_type == "organic_results":
        title = i["title"]
        titles.append(title)
        print(title) 

context = {"titles":titles}
```

and iterate over it on your template using the for loop:

```
{%for title in titles %}{{ title }}{%endfor%}
```

Comment: I clearly said I don't want to use append method method. I know I can use it. please read my question first.